# Tumblr API2: Create A Photo Post with several Images

Tags: api, tumblr

Hi I have read the docs here:
http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting

I know how to upload one pic via the The photo 'source' URL parameter. like:

```
source: 'http://www.example.com/example.jpg'
```

How can I upload several pics in one photo post?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this on the API page link for photo uploads?

> data   Array (URL-encoded binary contents) Limit: 5 MB

You would pass in an array containing the image links containing the multiple values as data instead of a single source file.

Comment: Are you sure u understand it correctly? The 'data' here means image data of a local file. It has nothing to with the 'source' parameter which uploads a remote pic.

Comment: The source parameter does not upload multiple images, it uploads one image, use the data parameter and pass in an array of images for multiple images.